# Database design for segment reporting

Tags: database-design

I'm a Math and CS student interning for a financial services company and I have to develop a database for storing data from past segment income statements and generating new reports from new data once it is imported into the database. I've only done programming in Java and C++ so this is my first time dealing with databases and I have no real world application experience. I've been reading tons of books and articles on the subject so I understand the basics.

- I have quarterly segment reports in excel going back from the present
  until Jan 2010 (13 quarters)
- There are 2 different segments that categorize all the activity of
  the company. I'm just going to call them Segment1 and Segment2 for now.
- Both segments have multiple divisions operating in different
  countries (e.g. U.S. Division, Europe Division, etc). Segment1 has 6
  and Segment2 has 12.
- Each division services multiple industries (Construction, Energy,
  etc.) that depend on what segment they operate under . All divisions
  under Segment1 service 16 industries and all divisions under Segment2
  service 10 industries.
- There are 13 pieces of data that are tracked for each industry that are a mix of revenues and expenses.

I've come up with a design schema but I'm not very confident in it and would appreciate some advice. I just sketched it out and then recreated it in draw io. I'm new to this so I don't know if there are any programs that help with this process. Red = Primary Key. Blue = Foreign Key. I abbreviated the names of the data being tracked in this picture because they are long and I didn't feel like typing them out.

[image: Database design]

So once a design is set I want to focus on finding to way to import the current data from Excel to Access (My manager recommended Access because it's the only program he knows of but if something else is better, he's open to it). Right now, all the segment data are in excel spreadsheets in the same format separated by division and in folders that are grouped by quarter. The columns are the various industries and the rows are the data being tracked. There is a lot extraneous info in the spreadsheets that I would like to be able to get rid of when I import data. Is there a way to automate this using VBA or some other language or would I most likely be stuck copying and pasting?

Finally, the end goal of this database is to look for trends in data over time. Some examples of queries are:

- Calculating ratios of revenues to expenses for each quarter
- Finding out which segment has the most revenue/least expenses

This is my only project for the summer and I really want to do a good job on it. Any suggestions any step in the process are greatly appreciated.

Comment: IF you're com fortable enough with Java, you could use the Apache POI library to read Excel files and do something with them: either create simple text files ready to be loaded into your tables, or even dirctly insert them using JDBC.

Your table-structure seems straightforward enough.

Comment: Ok I'll look into that. Do you the pros/cons of using Apache vs. JDBC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A database that eases analysis is called a [Data Warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse).

It has a simpler and more denormalized schema than an operational database.

You can also perform a particular set of analysis operations on it, such as pivoting, slicing, dicing, drill-down, called [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing). These are often visualized in a [Pivot Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).

Ask your boss to buy you [Agile Data Warehouse Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0956817203) ($20ish). It is highly rated on Amazon.

Consider [Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/) open source OLAP server (works w Access), and [Saiku](http://demo.analytical-labs.com/) pivot tables

To ease loading of the warehouse, consider an ETL tool such as [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/).

Comment: I've been reading up on the subjects you posted and I think this may be the best way to get the information I want. Thanks for the recommendations!

Comment: [Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is another pivot table choice to connect to any OLAP server, like Mondrian and Microsoft Analysis server.